# the method getClickCount() is undefined for the type MouseEvent

Tags: java

```
private class MouseClickhandler extends MouseAdapter{

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){

        int a = event.getClickCount(); 
    }
```

Why do I receive the undefined method error? I checked MouseEvent API and the method exists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may have inadvertently imported the wrong class from your IDE. Ensure you import `java.awt.event.MouseEvent` and not for example `org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent` which doesnt contain the method

Comment: That's really a good point, sometimes IDE assumes you need a package that you don't really want.

Comment: I have imported those packages. Actually other methods like getButton() are allowed but methods like getX(), getY() or the one mentioned in the question receive this error which is very strange.

Comment: @ShayanAkbari Do you have another class called `MouseEvent` on your classpath?